# Windows batch/ Pick a number in a text file

Tags: windows, batch

I am on a windows computer and (thanks to a previous question) i have a text file with my HDD info. I just wanna pick the power on hours Info.

The line look like that :"Power-On Hours (POH),6 998,98,98,0,Ok".

It's inside the text and i want to pick the first number ( 6 998) to save it into a variable. 
I have try by find the begin of the line but i can'tt take a number of character beceause the number can be 2 or 20 000.
How can i do it? 
Thanks for the help ! And have a nice day  :) 
PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does the answer I gave to your previous question not work for you? The number  you want is in `%%m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want to pick the first number

> The line look like that :"Power-On Hours (POH),6 998,98,98,0,Ok".

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%l in (`type smart.txt ^| findstr /c:"Power-On Hours (POH)"`) do (
    set _variable=%%m
    echo !_variable!
    )
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for /f` and break out of it after setting the variable:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr "POH" "file.txt"') do set number=%%a&goto a
:a
echo %number%
```